Change Button Status on ComboBox Selection Change
I'm working on a code that works as below:

ComboBox with multiple parameters that a user chooses from
a Button that is enabled/Disabled based on the user selection

So, for now, this is what I have. A ComboBox with multiple parameters, and a button.
XAML Code:
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="169,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" SelectionChanged="cmbBox_SelectionChanged">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Please Select ..." IsSelected="True"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
 </ComboBox>
 <Button x:Name="generateButton" Content="Generate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True" Click="generateButton_Click"/>

CS Code:
private void cmbBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (cmbBox.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))
        generateButton.IsEnabled = false;
    else
        generateButton.IsEnabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show(((ComboBoxItem)cmbBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
}

private void generateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("BTN Clicked");
    MessageBox.Show(((ComboBoxItem)cmbBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
}

When I try to run this part of the code, it gives an error on:
generateButton.IsEnabled = false;
And doesn't run. If I comment these lines that sets the status of the button to enabled or disabled, the code runs normally.
I'm not sure what is wrong here. Especially that when I set the button to disabled in the mainwindow() function or the generateButton_Click() it works normally. I mean, it disables the button normally, but I can't enable again since it is not clickable.

just add a null check on your button in the event handler of your combobox, set your button disabled by default in the XAML and this should work as expected

@AlexR can you guide me on this part?

I mean, I can set it to disabled in the XAML. But how can I achieve the null check?

"SelectionChanged" "usually" fires on startup / Loaded. Button is instantiated, and "loaded" "after" the ComboBox. I suspect Button is being acccessed in SelectionChanged before it is ready for "interaction".

Yes that's right the button is not "there" when the selection event pop due to the IsSelected in the XAML. @sikas you just have to add if(generateButton != null) around your code in the cmbBox_SelectionChanged

if you change the tag order, you solve the problem

Button tag
After used ComboBox tag

Example:
<Button x:Name="generateButton" .... />
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" ...>
    ...
</ComboBox>


The SelectionChanged event is fired before the Button control has been instantiated. You don't want your code to be executed before this happens.
You can easily fix this by adding a condition that checks whether the ComboBox has been loaded, and simply return immediately if it hasn't:
private void cmbBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!cmbBox.IsLoaded)
        return;

    if (cmbBox.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))
        generateButton.IsEnabled = false;
    else
        generateButton.IsEnabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show(((ComboBoxItem)cmbBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());
}

